# Timezone conversion not working

Tags: php, time

To get timestamps to be in the user's time period, I have set up a timezone conversion tool with PHP for my posting system. Basically the user sets their own timezone through a dropdown, and this is stored on the database as a PHP timezone - so if I select GMT, the value in the database would be `Europe/London`.

The idea is then to take this from the database and plug it into a timezone conversion piece of code, but this presently isn't converting anything at all. Can anyone see the problem?

**doMessage.php**

```
$date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
$user_tz = $result['time'];
$schedule_date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone($user_tz) );
$schedule_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date =  $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**core/init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = new PDO('this is all correct');

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $i = $_SESSION['id'];

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:i");
    $query->bindParam(":i",$i);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch();

    $ver = $result["activated"];

    if($ver == 0) {
    echo "Please <a href='activate.php'>verify your account.</a>";
    }
    }
else {
echo "Please <a href='login.php'>log in.</a>";
$guest = True;
}
```

Comment: If user isn't inputing any datetime, why do you need to convert it? `doMessage.php` part is just nonsense. You already got datetime in server timezone.

Comment: `if I select GMT, the value in the database would be Europe/London` - GMT is not the same thing as Europe/London - the latter has daylight savings time (BST) where applicable.

Comment: @symcbean: I was just trying to say that, for the rest of the world GMT = UTC, but UK has timezone named as GMT when not in DST, and BST when in DST.

Comment: No, GMT isn't the same thing as UTC either - but at least you're only a fraction of a second out this time. And UK does not have a timeszone named GMT.

Comment: @symcbean: instead of `=` I should wrote `≈`, but didn't had time to find it on my keyboard ;) Technically they are different, but in casual use GMT is same as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

To get current date and time of GMT, just this is enough:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$current_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A T")

echo $current_date;
```

This outputs 2013-12-30 5:30:20 AM GMT

Comment: No, I'm trying to get it so that the date is relevant to every user, whether they are in Russia or in Britain. Setting to one time zone only doesn't achieve this.